# Why doesn't the Google Map in Cordova/Ionic always load in certain devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, google-maps

I am trying to figure out why sometimes the Google Map in my Ionic app does not always load in certain Android/iOS devices. It's a hit and miss issue and at first I thought it could be network or GPS issues affecting it, but the issue also happens when these are clearly up and running.

Could it be that the Google Map Javascript API faces outages lasting for a few seconds?

Comment: I have the same problem ! did you find any solution ?

Comment: It does not happen very often, but I noticed that it only happens when network coverage/phone reception is lacking. Therefore it is probably due to connection issues with the network.